# Rails 3.0.11 : attributes= on a parent model will call validations on nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, nested

I'm having an issue working with Rails 3.0.11 on a project.
I have a parent model called Candidate which has_one many nested_models.

I use nested_forms to save candidates in 2 ways :
-> without validations => I need to save "work in progress"
-> with validations => before going to next step

My issue concerns the first point : "without validations". I can't use update_attributes to mass-assign in my controller because it calls validations. I've tried a simple @candidate.attributes = params[:candidate] but it's wrong too because it will calls validation on nested model (through a classic save).

My problem is that even if I don't save my parent model (I'm just doing a mass-assign), nested model are saved and validations are triggered...

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Yoann.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be several ways to not validate objects, though I don't know for sure how they behave when using nested attributes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Since you write that you have tried bypassing validation by using `update_attributes`, perhaps you should try conditional validation instead on your nested model. Something like this maybe:

`validates :some_stuff, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { |record| record.parent.complete? }`